# Cannot boot after GPU driver installation

Tags: drivers, 18.04, graphics, 64-bit, amd-processor

I got a problem as the following attached image after installing new GPU drivers: PowerColor Red Devil Radeon™ RX 5700 and try to install its driver via this instruction https://www.amd.com/en/support/kb/release-notes/rn-amdgpu-unified-navi-linux.

After installation, if I directly connect a monitor via GPU, it can work well. Otherwise, it does work if I directly connect a monitor via CPU. Also, if I uninstall the drivers, my computer can work well.

I would really appreciate it if you can help me out. Thanks!
My OS:
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic
[image]